# How to move mouse pointer to a specific location on the screen AT BOOT?

Tags: raspbian, boot, cron, mouse

I recently downloaded the latest and greatest Raspbian OS for my PI, enabled hide function on taskbar and have installed xdotool. For what I want to use PI for, I need to have the taskbar hidden at all time even at Boot. Apparently, the latest Raspbian automatically moves the mouse pointer to startup or start button at boot. That enables the taskbar visibility. So, to avoid this I want to be able to move the mouse pointer away from the taskbar completely as soon as it boots. I have looked around on the Internet for answer, but I can't get anything working. I have tested the command I want to run on the terminal and it works as it should.

First I tried **Crontab**: `@reboot xdotool mousemove 300 250`
absolutely it does NOTHING at boot.

Second I tried **rc.local**: `xdotool mousemove 300 250`
it did nothing either.

Third I put this command into a script file and tried to execute the script at reboot. It didn't work either.

So, I am confused. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

The file `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` includes the line `@point-rpi`

Description for point-rpi is:

> Locate the mouse pointer over the menu button
>
> This tool determines the current location of the menu button on the taskbar, and positions the mouse pointer over it, to trigger the hover behaviour (button highlight and tooltip).

Presumably, if you remove that line it will no longer position the cursor on the taskbar.

[Source for point-rpi](https://github.com/raspberrypi-ui/point-rpi)

Answer (score 3):

> No need to install xdotool or whatever. go to:
>   `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`
>
> and comment out the line `@point-rpi` and remember, it will hide/center
>   the mouse pointer, not move it.

The path has changed as of Nov 2018 for the RPi. You can now find it here : `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

Answer (score 2):

No need to install xdotool or whatever.
go to:

```
/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

and comment out the line `@point-rpi` and remember, it will hide/center the mouse pointer, not move it.

Answer (score 1):

The fallowing worked for me.

```
@reboot sleep 5 && xdotool mousemove 300 250
```

I'm not sure of the boot process but it probably got to do with the fact that xdtool has not started by the time you execute that command.

Answer (score 1):

Look like `@point-rpi` was deprecated.
Now it's a property in `/home/pi/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel` for default user

```
Global {
  ...
  point_at_menu=1
```

Change it to `point_at_menu=0` to disable pointing at menu on startup.

Credits to https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=248530#p1590287

Answer (score 0):

Install the xautomation package

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation
```

Now we have xte, which can simulate the movement of the mouse and keyboard keypress

Examples of xte usage

Move the cursor to the point x = 10 and y = 20 on the screen grid

```
xte 'mousemove 10 20'
```

Shift relative to the current cursor location on x = 10 and y = 10

```
xte 'mousermove 10 10'
```

Source: https://anton.logvinenko.name/en/blog/emulation-of-mouse-movements-and-keystrokes.html