# which action (command) determines the location of the mouse pointer upon login / boot?

Tags: raspbian, boot, login, mouse

After boot / login in Raspbian (Jessie, Stretch, ...), the mouse pointer appears at the location of the raspberry icon at the upper left corner of the screen. What action or command determines that location during boot / login, and when is this done?

When searching related information here on SE I've found [this related question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/67791/63024), but it doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: Why does the position matter? What are you trying to accomplish and why? How do the related question's answers not work for you?

Comment: Well I've actually asked myself the very question I've posted here. I've 2 purposes: 1) understand how the mouse pointer is moved and 2) move the pointer in a window I'm opening at boot. The related question doesn't answer 1) (neither `xdotool` nor `xautomation` are installed on my system) and provides solutions using these commands, but then there's another mechanism which moves the pointer at or after login, I'd like to know what it is and hack it.